# Issues with resize on FF 8 on Mac?

Tags: firefox, resize

I have been pulling my hair out trying to do some dynamic div resizing based on window/body resize events. I first started with javascript, then tried jQuery, and have even tried other "working" demos but almost every one crashes FF (or at least causes the active window to go all white). Is anyone else experiencing this?

For example, if I go to:
http://jsbin.com/ucolu

and try to resize my FF window, it crashes FF, as do most others.
The only stable resize I have found is via Ben Alman's plugin at:
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/examples/resize/

Any ideas?

Comment: If you take out the alert from inside the resize handler, do you still see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because the event fires over and over as you drag the window (as opposed to waiting for you to finish resizing, then firing just once).

You can throttle the handler to make it work, so that it only updates periodically as you drag the window size (say, every 500 milliseconds).

Basically, you'd use `set_timeout` to call the function that resizes the div. The resize event handler only clears the timeout and resets it. Once the user stops resizing the window, the timeout will finally be able to run and the screen will update. If the user drags really slowly, or pauses, then the screen can update "mid-resize".

Comment: The event does fire multiple times as you resize, but why should that be a problem?

Comment: In this case, it is the `alert` that is causing the problem. But generally speaking, if you put a bunch of complex code / repaints into a handler that gets fired off all the time, you're going to have a problem.